# Flutter use variable from another class

Tags: flutter

how can i use a variable from another class in flutter? I want to pass the variable (randomName) to another class and use it. How i can do that?

```
Future<void> showNotification(int id, String title, String body) async {
    // Generate a new random name
    final random = new Random();
    final randomName = names[random.nextInt(names.length)];

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(
      id,
      title,
      body = randomName,
      RepeatInterval
          .everyMinute, //schedule the notification to show after 2 seconds.
      const NotificationDetails(
        // Android details
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('main_channel', 'Main Channel',
            channelDescription: "hello",
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.max),
        // iOS details
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails(
          sound: 'default.wav',
          presentAlert: true,
          presentBadge: true,
          presentSound: true,
        ),
      ),

      // Type of time interpretation
      androidAllowWhileIdle:
          true, // To show notification even when the app is closed
    );
  }
```

```
 onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        showToast();
                        NotificationService().showNotification(
                            1, 'Hello ${widget.userPost}', 'You');
                      });
                    },
```

I want to use in here in the place of 'You'. Or I can use directly from showNotification? Thx in advance

I've tried with @override

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class called RandomName:

```
class RandomName {
  final String name;
  RandomName({required this.name});
  get getName => name;
}
```

and call the constructor with the name and get the name from the class using a getter method:

```
 RandomName name = RandomName(name:"ThisIsARandomName");
 print(name.getName);
```